# How do I provide the github credentials to the unleash-maven-plugin?

Tags: git, maven, github, release, maven-release-plugin

I have a quite simple maven project published to github where I have 2FA enabled. I'd like to use the [unleash-maven-plugin](https://github.com/shillner/unleash-maven-plugin) to release new versions (looks like an improved/refreshed `maven-release-plugin`). I followed the instructions, but it's not very specific about how to provide the credentials. I can either use username/password (which can't work due to 2FA, can it?) or the passphrase to a private key in my `~/.ssh`.

I tried it with an `https` and a `git` connection and got this error while querying the remote git repository for tag '1.0.0': `Algorithm negotiation fail`.

What do I have to do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

In documentation is:

```
Custom SCM credentials
Sometimes it is necessary to provide SCM credentials to the SCM provider. This can be the case if the system does not cache the credentials or if you want to make SCM changes as a specific user. You can use the parameters scmUsername adn scmPassword for this purpose. When calling the goal from command line and providing these parameters through system properties the call would look like this:

mvn unleash:perform -Dunleash.scmUsername=... -Dunleash.scmPassword=...
```

Have you tried with:

```
mvn unleash:perform -Dunleash.scmSshPassphrase=<private key here>
```

Or:

```
PRIVATE_KEY=<private key>

mvn unleash:perform -Dunleash.scmSshPassphraseEnvVar=PRIVATE_KEY
```

Comment: The private key itself in a passphrase parameter?!? This sounds so strange (and is not documented) that I'm reluctant to even try!